# Read Protobuf data without schema

Tags: protocol-buffers

One is the original data, the other is the data converted by the web analyzer. How can I convert the data into the web analyzer with C#? I don't have a model.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a schema, frankly you need to reverse engineer one. Or chase down the source of the data and obtain the existing one, which is usually much easier.

Protobuf is an ambiguous format without it, and there is no one correct single way if decoding many of the "wire types". You can use tools like `protoc` (in decode-raw mode), or https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to try and decipher the raw data to try and put a schema together, but it is a little tedious and often requires some knowledge of what the data should *be*. For example, a "variant" - after the varint step - could be:

- an enum
- a twos-complement signed integer
- a twos-complement unsigned integer
- a zig-zag signed integer

Plus for the last 3 options, the same payload could be 32-bit or 64-bit (this doesn't change the value, but may change things if a later value is larger).

If you need help, I might be able to take a look - I've reverse engineered protobuf schemas many times.

---

If you just want raw access to the interpreted stream, protobuf-net has a `ProtoReader` type that works broadly like `XmlReader` etc, and may help you. But all of the ambiguities described above will remain.

Comment: Look at my web auto parsing. How does it work? I just want to parse it like this, and I don't need to parse it into a regular model or JSON

Comment: Is there any relevant code? First of all, thank you. I'm from China. China doesn't have such information.

Comment: The website you gave is easy to use. How should I implement this code with C#?

Comment: I use the data intercepted by the mitmproxy, which is well parsed automatically. But I don't use C to operate him

Comment: download url  https://pan.baidu.com/s/1FV8io_cgVdayJtTX-ynrSg password:ss2s

Comment: @binbin846 that website is written in C#; the important type there is `ProtoReader`, in protobuf-net - basically you just loop over each field in turn; I'm not going to be very available now due to holiday reason, but: the code for that website is on github

Comment: Is there a website?

Comment: @binbin846 "is there a website?" - for what, specifically? if you mean https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode, then... um, yes? if you mean the code for that site: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/tree/master/src/protogen.site - if you mean protobuf more generally, then https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf